# how to fit four parameter logistic regression (poisson) R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, poisson

I'm trying to fit a four parameter logistic regression to model bird species richness (Patch_Richness) in response to forest cover (FOREST500). I need to add km as a co-variable to the model (km= kilometers), I'm trying the following (code) but not sure if "km" is properly included in the formula, I just added km after the predictor (FOREST500)

```
logip=function(p,lambda,x){
  a=p[1]
  b=p[2]
  c=p[3]
  d=p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-FOREST500+km)/c)))
  -sum(dpois(x,lambda=Riq1, log=TRUE))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")
modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=30,b=30, c=3,d=20), data=list(x=Patch_Richness))
summary(modTR.log)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Logistic regression and Poisson regression are two different types of generalized linear models. Bird richness sounds like count data, so Poisson is probably what you are looking for. Is there a reason that you don't want to use a package like 'lme4' to do this? It would help you be more confident that everything is being implemented correctly.